# Debug.Print 2D array Value

Tags: vba, solidworks

Hello ı have strange array as variant. I want to print Name key  value but ı don't know how to declare it. I try run the line below but it can't works.

```
Debug.Print vBodies(0,Name) or Debug.Print vBodies(0).Name
```

[image]

Comment: Run time error 13 Type Mismatch

Comment: Yes, same error. Did ı declare it clearly

Comment: Where is `vBodies` getting declared and set?

Comment: I did it. This works "Debug.Print vBodies(0).Name". I  declared it after  function . Now ı did it in function. Sorry for taking your time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not 100% solution but it  might help to show the array fields name

```
          ' arr is the array to check
           Dim subarr as Variant
           For Each subarr In arr
                  Debug.Print subarr & " : " & arr(subarr)
           Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast vBodies(0) to SldWorks.Body2 Object to access its properties

```
Dim swBody As SldWorks.Body2
Set swBody = vBodies(0)
Debug.Print swBody.Name
```